# Unpredictable counting of number

Tags: algorithm, random, permutation

Say I have a 32-bit integer. Initially I seed this *black box* with something random/secret.

Each time I call, advance, I get the next number in the sequence but the next number in the sequence isn't necessarily the the next largest number, as with `++` it's something unpredictable. I've done this using a permutation table but that requires a lot of space and I was wondering if anyone knows of a specific construct that would give me an entire range in some deterministic order that's based on some seed value and then only yield each value exactly once per cycle.

Does anyone know of such a scheme?

Comment: Something like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register

Comment: You're asking for a random generation but in an order based on a seed value? Can you clarify? I'm confused.

Comment: @Daniel I think a linear feedback shift register is what I'm looking for. The random part is misleading, I'll clean some of that up.

Comment: Do you need the sequence to be unpredictable such that it isn't possible to determine the seed using the generator's output?  Because if so then you'll need to use a [cryptographic prng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot It doesn't need to be secure per se but the harder it is to predict the better in my opinion. The trick for me is to cycle each value exactly once in a range in some unpredictable manner.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren That's what all pseudo-random number generators whose state space is the same size as their seed space do:  Linear feedback shift register generators, linear congruential generators, prime modulus multiplicative generators.  There's some pretty good number theory that will tell you when and if the full cycle is achievable based on the specific transformation and coefficients you use.

Comment: @pjs OK, well then that's my answer. I was looking for linear feedback shift register. And now that I've had a chance to play a little with the code on Wikipedia I get that what I asked for is precisely this. I just didn't know what to search for. Now I do, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Blender If you just post your comment as an answer, I'd happily accept it.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren: I just know of the name and that they pseudo-randomly cycle through a space, touching each element only once. That's really about all I can say.

Comment: @Blender Well, it's either that or I delete the question. Maybe someone else eventually comes along but this has pretty much served it's purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an intresting answer to a question on [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/344) by Thomas Pornin that goes into how to design a secure [alternating step generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_step_generator) (ASG).

It's not the fastest solution to my problem but I think it will do.

I wrote this code to test my theory

```
struct Lfsr
{
    public readonly int State;

    public Lfsr(int seed)
    {
        this.State = seed;
    }

    public Lfsr Advance()
    {
        var bit = ((State >> 30) ^ (State >> 27)) & 1; //  ^ (State >> 1) ^ (State >> 0)
        return new Lfsr(((State << 1) | bit) & 0x7fffffff);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var n = 0;

    var lfsr = new Lfsr(1);

    do
    {
        lfsr = lfsr.Advance();

        ++n;
    }
    while (lfsr.State != 1);

    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

On my machine it took about 7 seconds to cycle through with a period of 2147483647 counted numbers. In order to make it secure you'd have to combine these into an ASG and use three times as large linear feedback shift registers (LFSRs).

You also need to use maximal-length feedback polynomials for strength. the Wikipedia article references a [PDF](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf) that lists maximal-length feedback polynomials up to 168-bits in length.